# File Permission error in Google Cloud (GKE) Kubernetes Docker Container

Tags: bash, docker, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, file-permissions

I am trying to run a initialisation script within my Docker container which is deployed using the Kubernetes **kubectl** command on the Google Cloud Container Engine (GKE).

The script executes without error in the docker container on my local system, but does not seem to work on GKE.

I am using the *root* account to execute the script on GKE.

The Dockerfile environment variable is set to: **ENV SUEXECUSERGROUP false**

The path to shell script is mapped to an external persistent disk. I have done this so that I do not need to hardcode any paths within the shell script:

> /*path-to-shell-script*/ is mapped to ~/parent-folder

The docker entry point is:

> /usr/local/bin/*docker-entrypoint.sh*

The shell script is located at:

> shell script /*path-to-shell-script*/fix.sh

When the container is loading (initialisation) I receive the following error:

> ./fix.sh: Permission denied

When I run **ls -lad /*path-to-shell-script*/** from within the container, I get the following output:

> drwxr-sr-x 19 apache apache 4096 /*path-to-shell-script*/

**ls -la /*path-to-shell-script*/** also shows:

> ...
>   -rwxrwxr-x  1 root   root         988 fix.sh
>   ...

Comment: Not sure about Google Cloud, but this can normally be associated with SELinux running on the host

Comment: @RamanSailopal From what I gather, Google Cloud Container Engine uses a flavour of CoreOS (a very basic linux/unix) to host the docker/kubernetes deployment environment. But since I am running the commands as Root why would this make a difference?

Comment: SELinux is an extended security hardening process that sand-boxes processes running (even as root) to ensure that if compromised, the processes don't "brick" the system. Apparently CoreOS supports SELinux as so it is worth checking with the command "sestatus"